# Customising NSDocument's NSSavePanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nssavepanel

As I edit and then try to close a document in my document-based app, an `NSSavePanel` pops up. 
It says, *"Do you want to save the changes made to the document “Untitled”?"*

Is there any way to alter this message? `-setMessage:` does not do anything, apple's sample code called *[CustomSave](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomSave/Introduction/Intro.html)* apparently uses that method without any apparent effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's technical support :

*Overriding "autosavesInPlace” that returns YES changes the UI behavior of the unsaved changes save dialog, you can’t override the message string in that case.  I recommend you continue to adopt auto save in place as this is more common now for document-based Cocoa apps.*

*Saving on an unnamed document for the first time will allow for your message string to appear in the save dialog, but a "close operation" of an unnamed document, the save changes alert string becomes part of the save dialog near the top, not allowing for room for your message string.*